# INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER - Android Emulator Installation error

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

**Issue:**

Installation failed in Emulator.

**Error Log:**

```
Session 'app': Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

- Uninstalled app in Emulator and did a fresh installation.

**Reason:**

- A change in `applicationId` is the cause of the error.
- The test app version installed in emulator had *com.example.test* as `applicationId`.
- The Release version had *com.casp.proc* [changed to include brand] as `applicationId`.
- Release version failed to get installed in Emulator because provider name *com.casp.proc.fileprovider (in package com.casp.proc)* is already used by `com.example.test` , resulting in conflict.

**build.gradle (:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.casp.pro"
        minSdkVersion 26
        
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 3
        versionName "3.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
```